# WAMP ignore my.ini

Tags: mysql, wamp

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17 has my.ini. I add text `log=c:/wamp/logs/mysql_query.log` but it's not working.

Any changes do not work. I tried to rename the file myblablabla.ini, but WAMP server successfully started. I think, he uses a different configuration file. How to find it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the 64bit version of WAMPServer 2.4 or 2.5 there was a little mistake in the release.

MySQL looks in its ini file for a section that matches its service name, to get its parameters from. The 64bit MySQL Service is called `wampmysqld64` and therefore the `my.ini` section header should also be `wampmysqld64`

Use the wampmanager menus to edit `my.ini` like this

```
wampmanager -> MYSQL -> my.ini
```

So edit your `my.ini` and find this line

```
[wampmysqld]
```

Then change it to

```
[wampmysqld64]
```

MySQL will now pickup the parameters you set within that section.

Comment: Fanks for your advice.

I'm realy using the 64bit version of WAMPServer 2.5. I opened my.ini and changed [wampmysqld] to [wampmysqld64]. After them WAMP doesn't start. When I can see log?

Comment: Use the wampmanager menus to look at `wampmanager->MySQL->ErrorLog` or `wampmanager->Apache->ErrorLog` also try looking at the Windows Event Viewer for message from Apache and MySQL. But if thats all you changed then I would say that you messed up when adding stuff to `my.ini` while it was not seeing your changes

Comment: Error causes a row `log = c:/wamp/logs/mysql_query.log`. I changed it to `general-log=1
general-log-file = c:/wamp/logs/mysql_query.log` and it's ok. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly , I can't find `my.ini` when I am using WAMPSERVER, I didn't install MySQL separately, Thanks.

Comment: @TiyebBellal Use the wampmanager menu `wampmanager -> MYSQL -> my.ini` that will open my.ini in your default editor

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct but not totally, at least for me.
I'm using wampserver 2.5 64bit.
I must add BOTH [wampmysqld64] and [mysqld64] section in my .ini file in order to make it works!

```
[wampmysqld64]
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

[mysqld64]
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Go to wamp icon and do like this:
1. Wamp > MySQL > MySQL console

2. Run `select @@sql_mode;` // check results
3. Wamp > MySQL > my.ini // edit file with the code I've mentioned above.
4. Restart wamp all services
5. Run `select @@sql_mode;` // check results, need to be:

`+--------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
| NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+`

Comment: Downvoted and no comment.. for what reason little guy? I'm trying to help here... This is one by one the situation I had and maybe other will have the same issue!
If it works for someone, perfect, my pleasure to help!
If no, skip to the next solution.
Good luck ;)

Comment: Just tried adding datadir="D:/bitnami/data" to both sections, no joy.  Any ideas?